# Subtracting or comparing to a limit

Tags: php, mysql

With these tables:

**workshops**

```
WorkshopID | WorkshopName | WorkshopLimit
    1         Workshop A         10
    2         Workshop B         20
    3         Workshop C         30
    4         Workshop D         40
    5         Workshop E         50
```

**workshop_participants**

```
ParticipantID | RegistrantID | WorkshopID
      1              1             1
      2              1             2
      3              2             3
      4              3             2
      5              3             5
      6              4             1
      7              4             4
      8              5             4
```

Is it faster to just subtract and update the number of `WorkshopLimit` for each registration, or count the total number of participants of a certain workshop then subtract it to the `WorkshopLimit` *(without updating `WorkshopLimit`)* ?

An example of usage for this is when I will check the remaining slot of a certain workshop.

Comment: count the total number of participants of a certain workshop then subtract it to the WorkshopLimit (without updating WorkshopLimit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is faster to run a simple select statement like `SELECT WorkshopLimit FROM workshops WHERE id = 42` to read a simple value from a `datarow` to check the remaining open seats in a workshop than to use a more complex query involving an aggregate function like `COUNT(...)` to calculate the remaining open seats on demand all the time.

However, it is most likely not speed-wise relevant at all if you update the remaining open seats value in the `workshops` table at each registration OR if you calculate the remaining seats on the fly when needed. They are both too fast to be relevant for your decision to use one  approach or the other.

**TL;DR** =  It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how strict of your WorkshopLimit. If over-registration is prohibited, updating WorkshopLimit is an easy way to guard the rule. Make registration and updating WorkshopLimit in a transaction, if WorkshopLimit is less than 0, rollback the transaction and cancel the registration.

If over-registration is allowed, both solution is acceptable. As if you don't have huge data volume, performance difference should be minor.